# Trying to insert few records (Key and values) in collection (mongodb) if particular (Key:value) is not present using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

In our application, everyday we do on-boarding of many customers manually, so we thought to include it in the current backend python code.

So the logic we decided is, if a new customer logs in our application, it should check the existing collection in DB whether the particular (key:value) is existing, if not it should create a new customer (Key:value) in the collection of the mongoDB.

Code that i tried,

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://userAdmin:r1ngR@18.214.18.11:27017/testdb",authSource="admin")
db = client['testdb']
col = db.customers
result = col.find( {"phone_number" : "14344666349"} )
print(result)
for doc in result:
    print (doc)
```

Please help to build on to the code if the given "key" - "phone_number" is not exist, then the new key:value to be inserted. Thank you!

Comment: I guess numbers must be unique so I'd recommend using `find_one`. Then you can check with `if not result`. This means no record with that info was found on your database.
`find_one` (I think also `find`) returns `None` if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://userAdmin:r1ngR@18.214.18.11:27017/testdb",authSource="admin")
db = client['testdb']
col = db.customers
# If we want only 1 record, we use find_one
result = col.find_one( {"phone_number" : "14344666349"} )
# If nothing is found
if not result:
    col.insert_one(client_dict)

print(result)
for doc in result:
    print (doc)
```

A small note. I dont know if the credentials in your question are the real ones. But be careful with this, always put something like `user:password@ip`.

Comment: Thanks Manuel it works. Sure, these credentials and IP are all masked and its not the real ones..

Comment: Great! If the solution works please acccept the answer so the question gets reolved!